# Can't display all product categories on woocommerce in a plugin administration page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display all products category, but it returns

> => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

My code :

```
$woo_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );

print_r($woo_categories);
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Prior to 4.5.0, the first parameter of get_terms() was a taxonomy or list of taxonomies:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args array:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

you should set taxonomy inside array

```
$woo_categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );

print_r($woo_categories);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..
But it's still doesn't work :
`
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] =&gt; Array
        (
            [invalid_taxonomy] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; Invalid taxonomy.
                )

        )

    [error_data] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

)`

Comment: Code wich i wrote in my answer for your task - works fine for me. `$woo_categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );` this show me all categories and sort by count.
looks like your error not in this part. Do you have hooks to `get_terms` action? May be issue by some plugins or your hooks?

Comment: What do you mean by `get_terms' ?

Comment: [get_terms hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms/) or [get_terms_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/) this hooks can create error like this.

Comment: For example $categoriesad = get_terms( array(
 'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );

print_r($categoriesad);

Comment: Is working, but not woo_categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );

print_r($woo_categories);

Comment: This code will perfect work with woocommerce categories. Woo categories is the same taxonomy like categories.

Comment: May be some plugins block default get_terms result with product_cat taxonomy. Because on clean wordpress (latest) and clean woocommerce (latest) code from my answer work fine.

Comment: How can I test if get_tems is blocked ?